# TinyMCE - have to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, tinymce, turbolinks

When I navigate to a page with TinyMCE it displays regular textareas until I refresh the page because of turbolinks. This is a pretty well-documented issue and people generally recommend some form of the following:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
    <code here>
});
```

I've tried every variation on this to no avail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was that a lot of the discussion around this issue is quite outdated and doesn't take into account that turbolinks events have changed as of 5.0.0.

I was able to solve the problem with the following:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
   tinymce.remove();
   tinymce.init({selector:'.tinymce'});
});
```

A full list of turbolinks events can be found [here](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events)

Comment: excelent answer, you help me a lot

Comment: I actually had to use the `turbolink:render` event, it didn't work with `:load` for me. (Still with consecutive `tinymce.remove(); tinymce.init()`)

Comment: It's not working on my side. @Arun can you show your code, please?